# What is the right way to use pointers in union (e.g. allocate and free memory)? or is it possible?

Tags: c++

I am trying to fix bugs in an old project written by others. Below is part of the code I am working with now.

There are some things I am not clear about the usage of pointers in union. How the memory pointed by pointers in an union can be released? Should I allocate memory for pointers? Also I think they are other issues with the code, please kindly point them out. Thanks a lot!

Code:

```
class A
{
    long filePos; 

    union EU
    {

        float *recording;
        UINT64 timeStamp; 

        EU(): timeStamp((UINT64)0)  //should I allocate memory here?
        {
        }

        EU(const EU& eu)            
        {
            if(eu.timeStamp)       //is this the way to check which field of union is used currently?
                timeStamp = eu.timeStamp;
            else
                recording = eu.recording;


        }

        EU& operator=(const EU& eu)
        {
            if(this == &eu)
                return *this;

            if(eu.timeStamp)
                timeStamp = eu.timeStamp;
            else
                recording = eu.recording;


            return *this;
        }

        EU(UINT64 ts):timeStamp(ts)
        {   
        }

        ~EU()            
        {

        }

    }EU;
    public :
    inline A(long fpos, UINT64 ts) :filePos(fpos),EU(ts)
    {
    }

    inline A(const EDFItem & ei)
    {
        filePos = ei.filePos;
        EU=ei.EU;
    }


    ~A ()
    {

    }

    inline A& operator=(const A& ei)
    {
        if(this == &ei)
            return *this;
        filePos = ei.filePos;
        EU=ei.EU;

        return *this;

    }


}
```

Comment: Since `float *recording` and `UINT64 time` will be living in the same memory space, you can't use that to determine whether it is a pointer or time - because most likely both will be non-zero.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So is there any way to know what it is (pointer or time) ?

Comment: There is no (generally working) way to determine if a pointer is a pointer or a timestamp. If your timestamps are 64 bit and have the upper 32 bits set, on a 32-bit system, you could use that to see the difference. Otherwise, you will need some more bits somewhere to indicate if it's a pointer or not.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `UINT64 time;` should be `UINT64 timestamp;`...

There's lot's wrong with the code.  If `EU::recording` holds
a valid pointer, `EU::timestamp` will also be non-null, and
vice-versa.  (Probably: on a 32-bit big endian machine, a small
enough time stamp would not cause `recording` to be non-null.)
The copy constructor and assignment operator are superfluous
and confusing, since the test for the last initialized type is
incorrect.  They'll work, but more by chance than anything else.
And there is no need for the tests for self assignment.  (If you
needed them, the assignment operator probably wouldn't be thread
safe, but you don't need them here.)

As for how to manage the pointer: it's up to the user of the
union (`A`).  The union itself has no means of knowing whether
it contains a pointer or a timestamp, and no means of knowing
how the pointer was allocated.  As far as I can tell from the
code you've posted, the union never contains a pointer anyway,
and could be directly replaced by `UINT64 timestamp;`.  Which
would be the best solution, unless there's more to it than you
show.

Comment: Yes, it should be timeStamp, I already modified my code above. I only show a part of the code here. the pointer (recording) is used. I can't cut it off from the code.

Comment: @user1558064 In which case, the user of the `union` must keep track of whether `pointer` or `timeStamp` is active, and know what to do about managing `pointer`.  There's no way it can be done in the `union` itself.

Comment: Got it. So in case, I already know whether pointer or timestamp is used, I can release memory pointed by the pointer when the memory isn't used anymore. But for allocating memory for the pointer, it is not needed, because the pointer and time share memory. Am I understanding it right?

Comment: @user1558064 More or less.  The memory you release has to come from somewhere, and that somewhere should be outside of the union.  The union shouldn't really know anything about it.

Comment: Basically, all the work of managing the data in `EU` must be done by the `A` class.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Probably.  And it should probably be just a classical union, with no member functions.

Comment: @JamesKanze , can you please explain why "The memory you release has to come from somewhere, and that somewhere should be outside of the union. The union shouldn't really know anything about it."? Should I allocate memory for pointers in the union? and why? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user1558064 Just the opposite.  You _shouldn't_ allocate anything in the code for the `union`.  (In fact, I doubt that this union should have any code.)

Comment: @JamesKanze, can you please explain why I shouldn't allocate anything in the code for union? I ask this because I try to redesign this in a better way. Thanks.